# How to make an executable phar?

Tags: php, shebang, phar

I want to start a phar script as an executable, directly by doing `foo.phar <params>` instead of `php foo.phar <params>`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's easy by modifying the default stub (adding the shebang corresponding to php).

```
// start buffering. Mandatory to modify stub.
$phar->startBuffering();

// Get the default stub. You can create your own if you have specific needs
$defaultStub = $phar->createDefaultStub('index.php');

// Adding files
$phar->buildFromDirectory(__DIR__, '/\.php$/');

// Create a custom stub to add the shebang
$stub = "#!/usr/bin/php \n".$defaultStub;

// Add the stub
$phar->setStub($stub);

$phar->stopBuffering();
```

Comment: Since the PHP executable is not in `/usr/bin/php` on all systems, it's better to use `#!/usr/bin/env php` instead. See http://tech.vg.no/2012/02/21/dont-hardcode-php-executable-path-in-shebang/

Comment: nope, on windows you should do something like associate the .phar extension with PHP.

Comment: Getting a fully functional phar took me quite some time, I hope it can spare you some time https://github.com/8ctopus/webp8/blob/master/src/Compiler.php